# Diferença entre estas 2 urls.

Tags: php, url, url-amigável

No meu  estudo de PDO me deparei com o seguinte: possuo uma URL assim: www.site.com/admin/index?dir=artigo/create

Como criei uma função de remoção do .php dos arquivos na navegação a URL acima não funcionou.

Então decidi trocar o "?" por "&" e tirando o .php da URL, ficando assim:

www.site.com/admin/index&dir=artigo/create

e funcionou, ele buscou na pasta artigo o arquivo create e renderizou pra mim. 
Como isso pode afetar meu site? Segurança pode ser comprometida? Agradeço qualquer feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você está usando o servidor WEB Apache, provavelmente a opção *MultiViews* está ativa, neste caso é possível ignorar a extensão do arquivo e o próprio Apache irá determinar qual é o arquivo mais apropriado para ser chamado.

Isso não irá interferir na segurança da aplicação.